# Mouse click location on image

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do should be easy for a Js guy, but I am just a php guy (just a starter.). I need this for a project that I am doing now.

What I am trying to do is, get the click co-ordinates over the image and post it to a php script so that I can get the values and do the rest of the processing. (I dont know ajax, so this is the only way I can do that I suppose).

I found a code, but this shows the X and Y points as many times as I need. I want it to work just for one time.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function FindPosition(oElement)
{
if(typeof( oElement.offsetParent ) != "undefined")
{
for(var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent)
{
posX += oElement.offsetLeft;
posY += oElement.offsetTop;
}
return [ posX, posY ];
}
else
{
return [ oElement.x, oElement.y ];
}
}

function GetCoordinates(e)
{
var PosX = 0;
var PosY = 0;
var ImgPos;
ImgPos = FindPosition(myImg);
if (!e) var e = window.event;
if (e.pageX || e.pageY)
{
PosX = e.pageX;
PosY = e.pageY;
}
else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)
{
PosX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
+ document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
PosY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
+ document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
PosX = PosX - ImgPos[0];
PosY = PosY - ImgPos[1];
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = PosX;
document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = PosY;
}

//-->
</script>
<img src="newapp.jpg" alt="" id="myImgId" height="300" width="400"><p>Click on the image to get the coordinates.</p>


<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var myImg = document.getElementById("myImgId");
myImg.onmousedown = GetCoordinates;
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: You need to get e.clientX and e.clientY in image onclick event and then post them in php through ajax post script!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even do it without javascript (just with html and php ;)

```
<?php
  $foo_x=$_POST['foo_x'];
  $foo_y=$_POST['foo_y'];
  echo "X=$foo_x, Y=$foo_y ";
?>
<form action='' method=post>
  <input type="image" alt=' Finding coordinates of an image' src="xy-coordinates.jpg" name="foo" style=cursor:crosshair;/>
</form>
```

The key is the type-attribute set to `type="image"`.

Source and Demo: http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_image_coordinates.php

Comment: And I will call that as the best answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  $("image").click(function(e){
      var pageCoords = "( " + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY + " )";
      var clientCoords = "( " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY + " )";
      $("span:first").text("( e.pageX, e.pageY ) : " + pageCoords);
      $("span:last").text("( e.clientX, e.clientY ) : " + clientCoords);
    });​
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't I had this code to yours:

```
document.getElementById("x").value     = PosX;
document.getElementById("y").value= PosY;
```